# Как проверить какой аватар у facebook пользователя (дефолтный или нет)?

Tags: java, facebook

Мне нужно проверить, загрузил ли facebook пользователь аватар или использует дефолтный и если загрузил, то сохранить фото профиля в базу, если нет - установить значение null. Каким образом это можно сделать? Для получения используется класс Facebook:

`Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
byte[] photo = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfileImage();`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Есть web-приложение, в котором можно зарегистрироваться используя facebook account. При регистрации через facebook нужно узнать, какой аватар использует facebook user - дефортный или он установил свое фото. Если аватар не дефолтный, то сохранить его вместе с остальными данными этого пользователя в базу, если дефолтный, то установить значение аватару null